# Add multiple css classes @Html.LabelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I would like to add multiple css classes to @Html.Label for but it does not

I have already tried the following:

```
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "SerivcesRegistrationLabel" , "control-label col-md-2" })


   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "SerivcesRegistrationLabel"  "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Both of these give me errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place all of the class names in one string, each separated by a space.  Like:

```
@class = "SerivcesRegistrationLabel control-label col-md-2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Close. All attributes on Html helpers like `@id` and `@class` kind of simulate how the string will actually show up as an attribute, without actually doing anything to it. So you specify it exactly like you would on the actual element, with a space after each class.

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "SerivcesRegistrationLabel control-label col-md-2" })
```

Every time you use a comma, inside the `htmlAttributes`, it's expecting a new attribute, not another class again.